# Programmatic way to get output directory in Bookdown?

Tags: bookdown

Is there a way to detect the Bookdown output directory in code running within an RMarkdown document?

I'm happily using Bookdown to write tutorials using Python code.  To make the tutorial interactive, I want to make copies of the `.Rmd` files as Jupyter Notebooks, and put something like this at top of the relevant `.Rmd` files:

```
`r make_link_notebook()`
```

where the `make_link_notebook` function creates the Jupyter Notebook file, and makes a link to the notebook within the output document.

To do this, `make_link_notebook` needs to know where the Bookdown output directory is.  By default, of course, this is `_book`, but I am customizing this in some configuration files, so I want to be able to find the output directory programmatically.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `knitr::opts_knit$get("output.dir")`?

Comment: @grrrck - thanks for the suggestion, but yes, I did try that - it gives the directory of the source (`.Rmd`) file.   See [my Github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/773) for more discussion and suggestions by Github user `cderv`.